# Constant value of __TIME__ in whole program

Tags: c, time, macros, c-preprocessor

If I have a C program consisting of multiple C source files that each use the preprocessor directives `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`, is there any way I can make sure that the value is always the same for every instance in the current program?

I tried using a header file with `#define FIXED_TIME __TIME__`, hoping that would only be evaluated once, but I was wrong. If the compilation takes longer than 1 second the time in the C files will differ.

Is there any way I can make sure `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are the same when used in multiple files? Or do I have to resort to manually building the date and time strings in my Makefile and define these manually?

Comment: For what purpose do you need the time? It may affect the possible solution.

Comment: I'd like to print it to the screen in certain error conditions / debug outputs, kind of like a build identifier.

Comment: The issue is that if you have multiple source files in the project, for each source file compilation is a different call to gcc

Comment: You could wrap it in a function and `touch` its source as a pre-build step.

Comment: Sidenote: Compile time is not a really great indicator for build identifier. Ideally 2 builds of the same source code at 2 different points in time should produce identical binary. I would favor proper [version number scheme](https://semver.org/) and/or version control system changeset id.

Answer (score 4):

This is [a bit XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) but I think something like this really does belong in build infrastructure, since you're after some non-changing ID of the build itself.

For a simple/small project, I would consider adding something like

```
MAKE_TIME = $(date --iso-8601)
CFLAGS += -DBUILD_TIME=$(MAKE_TIME)
```

or something to the `Makefile`. This will of course still break if your project has many files and you just re-build a few of them, then they will be compiled with different value of `BUILD_TIME`.

One solution to that is to centralize the place in the actual code where the time is needed, into e.g. a single function, and use `BUILD_TIME` there only. Then the entire program will behave as if it was built when the file defining that function was built, which is at least better.